# Estou tentando mandar como resposta um array de "tarefas"(bot do zap)

Tags: javascript, node.js

To fazendo um bot para o zap, que recebe as tarefas e quando pede para ver as tarefas ele não quer mostrar o array

o codigo tá assim

> client.on('message', msg => {
> const content = msg.body
> // const id = msg.id

```
if(content.startsWith('#')){
    messages.push(content)
    msg.reply("Anotado Chefe ")
    console.log(messages)
    // console.log(id)

}
if(content === "Minhas tarefas"){
    console.log(messages)
    msg.reply(messages)
}
// console.log(Messages)})
```

Erro

> throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
> ^

Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serialize')

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O erro "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serialize')" está ocorrendo porque o método msg.reply requer um argumento válido para responder à mensagem. No caso, você está passando o array messages, mas ele não pode ser serializado para ser enviado como uma mensagem no WhatsApp.

Para corrigir isso, você pode transformar o array em uma string antes de enviá-la como resposta. Algo como:

```
if(content === "Minhas tarefas"){
    console.log(messages)
    msg.reply(messages.join('\n'))
}
```

Isso transformará o array messages em uma string separada por quebras de linha.

Comment: aaah entendi, tava pensando que poderia ser isso, funcionaria se eu usasse um map também? para listar cada item e enviar como mensagem?

Comment: Sim, você também pode usar o método map para formatar o conteúdo do array de mensagens.

Comment: Um exemplo de como usar:
```
if (content === "Minhas tarefas") {
    console.log(messages);
    msg.reply(messages.map((task, index) => `${index + 1}. ${task}`).join("\n"));
}
```
Neste exemplo, o método map é usado para transformar cada item do array em uma string no formato "número. tarefa". Em seguida, o método join é usado para juntar todas as strings em uma única string, separando-as por uma nova linha.

Comment: Pô cara muito obrigado, to fazendo aqui, tá ficando bacana, passa seu linkedin man